# I need to know how to display text based on text in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I have a column in my excel sheet that list titles of service tickets.  I need a formula that will display the following.

Example:
Reader 121 not reading badges

Expected result in the adjacent cell:
Display the text "Reader"

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to create a table of keywords to search and the desired return.  Then you can use various formulas like search and match to do what you want.

Comment: How would one do this?

Comment: Do you just need the first word from a sentence every time?  Or is there a specific requirement that you haven't mention above?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to extract the first word of the ticket, you could look for the first space in string position and then extract from left. 
Example (if "Display the text "Reader" is in B1) :

```
=LEFT(B3;FIND(" ";B3))
```

Hope this helps